# ¿por que me sale "uso de variable local no asignada" en C#?

Tags: c#

este es mi programa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Temperatura
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba un numero, el cual sera la temperatura en celsious");

            string temperatur = Console.ReadLine();
            int temperatura;
            int temper;
            if(int.TryParse(temperatur, out temper))
            {
                temperatura = temper;    
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El valor ingresado no es valido");
            }

            if (temperatura > 48)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir ropa ligera y de colores claros");
            }
            else if (temperatura > 29)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir traje de baño");
            }
            else if (temperatura > 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir camisetas de manga corta, pantalones de tela ligera, shorts y vestidos");
            }
            else if (temperatura > 19)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir playeras, camisetas de manga tres cuartos o larga, una chaqueta ligera y pantalones de mezclilla");
            }
            else if (temperatura < 19)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir prendas de algodón y un suéter para entrar en calor");
            }
            else if (temperatura < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cubrir el cuello, la cabeza y las manos, por lo que no deben faltar en su maleta bufandas, gorros y guantes");
            }
            else if (temperatura == 48)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir ropa ligera y de colores claros");
            }
            else if (temperatura == 29)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir traje de baño");
            }
            else if (temperatura == 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir camisetas de manga corta, pantalones de tela ligera, shorts y vestidos");
            }
            else if (temperatura == 19)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("vestir prendas de algodón y un suéter para entrar en calor");
            }
            else if (temperatura == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cubrir el cuello, la cabeza y las manos, por lo que no deben faltar en su maleta bufandas, gorros y guantes");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

en la parte donde dice if (temperatura > 48) me sale la palabra temperatura subrayada en rojo y solo ahi osea que en otras veces que esta la palabra no me aparece subrayada y cuando lo compilo me sale "uso de la variable local no asignada 'temperatura'"

Comment: Try int temperatura = 0;

Comment: esto debería preguntarse en [es.so]. Sin embargo, conviene que muestres más detalle para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Seguramente ese rojo te indique que hay posibilidades de que temperatura no se haya inicializado. Es decir, ¿qué pasa si en lugar de un número introduzco la palabra "hola" por consola? ¿Qué valor tiene entonces temperatura? Todos esos bloques if-else donde escribes distintas frases dependiendo del valor de temperatura deberían estar dentro del primer if, solo deben ejecutarse si se ha leído correctamente un entero. Como indica @fedorqui'SOstopharming' este es un sitio sobre la lengua española, no sobre programación, ya te ha indicado él donde debes preguntar pero bastantes pistas te he dado

Comment: Hola @Ronald ya he respondido tu pregunta. Dime con lo que sea a ver que tal ;D

Comment: Hola @cjimenecue me sirvio poner un return, gracias, me ayudaste

Comment: Me alegro @Ronald!! Si te parece que es correcta, te agradecería que la marcaras como correcta con el check verde debajo de la pregunta, :D pues así cierras la pregunta y puedes ayudar a otros a que encuentren la mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Porque `temperatura` puede llegar allí y no estar asignada. Eso se ve porque la inicializas al principio pero no le das ningún valor. Solo obtiene valor si la primera condición del `if` se cumple. En caso de que no se cumpla y ejecute el `else`, `temperatura` seguirá inicializada, pero sin ningún valor. Por eso, puede llegarte a ese primer `if (temperatura > 48)` sin inicializar y de ahí el error al compilar. Te explico lo que ocurre con comentarios en tu código:

```
int temperatura; // La inicializas pero temperatura no tiene ningún valor hasta ahora
int temper;
if(int.TryParse(temperatur, out temper))
{
    temperatura = temper;
    //Tan solo se le asigna un valor, el de 'temper' si llega a esta porción del código, cumpliéndose esta condición.
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("El valor ingresado no es valido");
    //Si la condición no se cumple, temperatura no tendrá ningún valor, pues aquí no le asignas nada.
}

// Si la condición del if anterior no se ha cumplido, temperatura solo estará inicializada, pero sin valor y por eso saltará el fallo en el siguiente if
if (temperatura > 48)
{
    Console.WriteLine("vestir ropa ligera y de colores claros");
}
```

Mi solución es que, en el primer `if(){}else{}` lo que puedes hacer es, en el `else`, o darle un valor por defecto si la condición no se cumple, o escribir un `return` par que el programa no siga si la condición no se cumple. Vamos, esto:

```
int temperatura;
int temper;
if(int.TryParse(temperatur, out temper))
{
    temperatura = temper;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("El valor ingresado no es valido");
    temperatura = 0; // Si falla, por lo menos el valor es 0
}
```

O esto:

```
int temperatura;
int temper;
if(int.TryParse(temperatur, out temper))
{
    temperatura = temper;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("El valor ingresado no es valido");
    return; // Si falla el programa finalizará y no seguirá con las siguientes comprobaciones.
}
```